# Trying to set up a new light fixture and confused by wire situation!

Tags: wiring, light

I am attempting to set up a new night fixture but I was confused when I opened the junction box on the ceiling. It contained two green wires together, two white wires together, and one blue. There was no previous light being hung when we moved in so I opened it for the first time.

I usually don't have trouble with lights but the extra wires threw me off as well as the unusual colors (I'm used to black and white). My question is which wires do I connect the black, white and ground wires from the new fixture to?

[image]

Comment: where in the world are you?

Comment: Is this a house or an apartment?

Comment: Are you quite sure the wires are *green* and not some other color? Are the green wires attached to the box also?  Are you in greater North America or the rest of the world?  Are there any other wires pushed up into the back of the box?

Comment: Where in the World of the Earth are you located ?- this is very important to know .. In the USA Residential / Commercial White wires are neutral lines, blacks are hot and greens are ground. Blue is not a normal color to be found except on the CEILING FAN EQUIPMENT itself . Measure the voltage (with a volt meter) between the blue and green, blue and white, white and green - post that info please.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that the blue is your switched hot. It is unusual to have the white and ground spliced with a single hot lead but since the place is probably wired in conduit they may not have brought the other hot into the box (as part of a multi wire branch circuit). I believe the fixture black should go to the blue then the white & ground to the white and ground on the fixture.